# Извлечение выбранных изображений из библиотеки в onActivityResult()

Tags: java, android

В приложении вызывается системное активити для выбора картинок из библиотеки, в случае когда выбирается несколько картинок то в активити их можно извлечь следующим образом

```
private void extractPickedImages(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        String realPath;

        try {
            // When an Image is picked
            if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_MULTIPLE_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && null != data) {

                imagesPathList = new ArrayList<String>();

                if (data.getData() != null) {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11)
                        realPath = RealPathUtil.getRealPathFromURI_BelowAPI11(this, data.getData());

                        // SDK >= 11 && SDK < 19
                    else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19)
                        realPath = RealPathUtil.getRealPathFromURI_API11to18(this, data.getData());

                        // SDK > 19 (Android 4.4)
                    else
                        realPath = RealPathUtil.getRealPathFromURI_API19(this, data.getData());


                    saveImageOnDevice(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT, data.getData().getPath(), realPath);

                    Log.e(TAG, "imageEncoded:" + realPath);

                } else {
                    if (data.getClipData() != null) {
                        ClipData mClipData = data.getClipData();
                        ArrayList<Uri> mArrayUri = new ArrayList<Uri>();
                        for (int i = 0; i < mClipData.getItemCount(); i++) {

                            ClipData.Item item = mClipData.getItemAt(i);
                            Uri uri = item.getUri();

                            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11)
                                realPath = RealPathUtil.getRealPathFromURI_BelowAPI11(this, uri);

                                // SDK >= 11 && SDK < 19
                            else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19)
                                realPath = RealPathUtil.getRealPathFromURI_API11to18(this, uri);

                                // SDK > 19 (Android 4.4)
                            else
                                realPath = RealPathUtil.getRealPathFromURI_API19(this, uri);


                            saveImageOnDevice(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT, uri.getPath(), realPath);

                            Log.e(TAG, "imageEncoded:" + realPath);

                            imagesPathList.add(realPath);
                        }
                        Log.v("LOG_TAG", "Selected Images" + mArrayUri.size());
                    }
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You haven't picked Image",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }
    }
```

В данном коде подчеркивается строка:

```
ClipData mClipData = data.getClipData();
```

и указывается что данный метод доступен в версии API 16, а в моем проекте минимальная версия API 15, чем можно заменить данные строки что бы работало на API 15 ?